# Prove that if $x_n \to q$ as $n \to \infty$ and if $f'(q) \neq 0$ then $q$ is a zero of $f$ for the secant method.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, numerical-methods, secant

The following is a textbook exercise that i am struggling with

> In the secant method prove that if $x_n \to q$ as $n \to \infty$ and if $f'(q) \neq 0$ then
>   $q$ is a zero of $f$

I think i have a fair idea about why intuitively it is true however I have troubles with the more rigorous proof, this is one of the first classes with proofs I am taking, so im am unsure as to what technique I should approach a problem like this with, and where to go from there?

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch no information given regarding that.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the name of the book?

Answer (score 1):

Under the stated assumptions, the secant root formula
$$
x_{n+1}=x_n-f(x_n)\frac{x_n-x_{n-1}}{f(x_n)-f(x_{n-1})}
$$
converges term wise to
$$
q=q-f(q)\frac1{f'(q)}
$$
so that indeed $f(q)=0$ for the limit point.

Comment: $f'$ should be continuous

Comment: Yes. It  would makesno sense to apply a method using linear approximation to a function that can not be linearly approximated.

Comment: True!   $ \ \ \ $